# external css, $.ajax, firefox, jquery . 

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

In my html I have 2 external css files

```
externalCSSContents = [];

function getExternalCSSContents(){
    var i, href;
    for (i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        href = document.styleSheets[i].href;
            if (href != null)
            {  
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: href, 
                    success: function (data) { 
                        externalCSSContents.push(data);
                    }
                });
            }
    }

}
getExternalCSSContents();
alert(externalCSSContents.length);
```

and this code is sometimes alerting 1 in firefox but permanently 2 in other browsers. What's wrong and how can i solve it?
**[Edit]** href sometimes = null in ff
**[Edit2]** I understood, sorry that I didn't mention about prefixfree.min.js attached. And with this library document.styleSheets[i].href was working in FireFox like in Chrome without it. ( document.styleSheets doesn't supported by Сhrome ). Thank you all for your answers and once more sorry for my inattentiveness.

Comment: Your code is leaking globals! You can fix it by putting `var i, href;` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I think you mean `var i, href;`. ;)

Comment: Did you step through the code?  Why does it alert 1?  Is it going through the loop twice but only putting one thing in the array or is it only looping once?  What is returned by document.styleSheets.length etc.

Comment: @James Montagne document.styleSheets.length = 2 all the time but href = null sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Another victim of AJAX. AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. The first part is in place here (Asynchronous ).

It could be that the AJAX call is not finished before reaching the alert. You can use a callback to be called when you AJAX function is finished.

```
externalCSSContents = [];

function getExternalCSSContents(callback){
    var i, href;
    for (i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        href = document.styleSheets[i].href;
            if (href != null)
            {  
                $.ajax({
                    url: href, 
                    success: function (data) { 
                        externalCSSContents.push(data);
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }
    }

}
getExternalCSSContents(downloadReady);

function downloadReady() {
    alert(externalCSSContents.length);
}
```

Comment: except for the `async: false`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the alert into the success function, you might have a race condition. You want the alert to wait until the AJAX call finishes.

Comment: With `async: false` the call blocks.